# proceed to next mySQL row JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, compare

I ran into  problem when my query returns result and I cannot check the next row.

```
//here i assume that only "regular" is correct room type
 public boolean checkAvalibility(String roomType, String checkInDate, String checkOutDate ) throws SQLException{
        database db = new database();
        db.connect();
        this.roomType = roomType;
        if(roomType!="regular"){
            System.out.println("please select correct room type");
            return false;
        }

             myStmt = db.myConn.prepareStatement("select * from Rooms where "
                        + "RoomType = ?");
             myStmt.setString(1, roomType);
             myRs = myStmt.executeQuery();
             boolean val = myRs.next();

             while(val){

                 if(roomType.equals(myRs.getString("RoomType"))){
                     System.out.println("correct room type");
                     isType =  true;
                 }

                 if(isType == true){
                     int roomNumber = myRs.getInt("idRooms");
                     if(checkDateAvailability(checkInDate, checkOutDate, roomNumber)==true){
                        return true;
                    }
                    else{
                        return false;
                    }
                 }

             }
                System.out.println();
                 return false;
         }
```

this code here

```
 private boolean checkDateAvailability(String checkInDate,String checkOutDate, int roomNumber) throws SQLException{
        database db = new database();
        db.connect();
         myStmt = db.myConn.prepareStatement("select idRooms, CheckIn, CheckOut from Rooms where "
                    + "CheckIn=? AND RoomType=?");
         myStmt.setString(1, checkInDate);
         myStmt.setString(2, roomType);
         myRs = myStmt.executeQuery();
         boolean val = myRs.next();

         while(val){
 //calcDateBeetween simply takes check-in date which is in database and current check-out date converts them to integer value and compares the difference     
      if(calcDateBetween(checkOutDate, myRs.getString("CheckIn")) <=0 ){
                System.out.println("You can book the room");
                return true;
            }

            else{
            System.out.println("Dates occupied");
            return false;
            }
         }
     if(val==false){
                System.out.println("room is available for booking date is empty");
                return true;
            }
         else{
             System.out.println("i have no idea of what im doing");
         }

    return false;
    }
```

As a pre-requirement, let's say I want to have only two rows and I don't need new records. If I send check-IN(!) date which matches the one in database (in Check-in column) then everything works fine, and I have print out saying that date is occupied. But if I send check-in value ex. 23-01-2015 and  check-out 03-02-2015 it does not go to `calcDateBetween()` method, probably assuming that if query was empty then the table can be updated and I have a printout that dates are available for booking. What can be the solution in this situation and why it does not compare dates in second case?
Thanks ![image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.  Instead of

```
boolean val = myRs.next();

while(val){
```

write

```
while(myRs.next()) {
```

Otherwise, you're not checking each time whether there are more rows; you're just using the same true or false value each time.

Also, within your `while` loop, you have `return true;` and `return false;` - and one of these is going to run each time.  That will make your method end, and your loop won't run again.  You probably don't want these `return` statements in there.

Comment: and should i just remove 'if(val==false)' then?

Comment: two things: 1) when I remove return statements program crashes since methods are supposed to return something and 2) any help with second part of my question? Why date is not checked with "27-01-2015" value?